# Why is importing CSS into a Less file breaking on Heroku?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, less, asset-pipeline

I have a less file that imports another less file, the latter importing some css files.

Here is my application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *= require simpliq/bootstrap.min
 *= require simpliq/style
 *= require simpliq/retina.min
 *= require gritter
 *= require bootstrap-overrides
 *= require custom-styles
 *= require mobile
 */
```

The `simpliq/style` file looks like this:

```
// Import External CSS Files
//===================================================================
@import "import.less";

// Import LESS Files
//===================================================================
@import "less/main.less";
@import "less/colors.less";
@import "less/mixins.less";
@import "less/header.less";
@import "less/navigation.less";
@import "less/buttons.less";
@import "less/tabs.less";
@import "less/forms.less";
@import "less/notifications_labels.less";
@import "less/modal.less";
@import "less/footer.less";

// My Custom Styles
//===================================================================
@import "less/charts.less";
@import "less/smallstats.less";
@import "less/discussions.less";
@import "less/chat.less";
@import "less/calendar.less";
@import "less/dashboard-list.less";
@import "less/tickets.less";
@import "less/todo.less";
@import "less/sliders_progress_bars.less";
@import "less/quick-buttons.less";
@import "less/circle-stats.less";
@import "less/others.less";
@import "less/switch-input.less";

// Components
//===================================================================
@import "less/datatables.less";
@import "less/justgage.less";
@import "less/nestable.less";
@import "less/wizard.less";
@import "less/datepicker.less";
@import "less/timepicker.less";
@import "less/daterangepicker.less";
@import "less/colorpicker.less";

// Example Pages
//===================================================================
@import "less/page-inbox.less";
@import "less/page-todo.less";
@import "less/page-profile.less";
@import "less/page-login.less";

// Responsive
//===================================================================
@import "less/responsive.less";
```

The problem arises with the first import, `@import "import.less";`, here's that file:

```
@import "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css";  
@import "fullcalendar.css";       
@import "chosen.css";         
@import "jquery.cleditor.css";      
@import "jquery.noty.css";        
@import "noty_theme_default.css";  
@import "uploadify.css";        
@import "jquery.gritter.css";     
@import "font-awesome.min.css";     
@import "glyphicons.css";       
@import "halflings.css";
@import "filetypes.css";
@import "social.css";
@import "xcharts.min.css";
@import "jquery.easy-pie-chart.css";
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300);  
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400);  
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script);
```

The error I'm getting on the production app on Heroku is this:

```
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/jquery.cleditor.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/jquery.noty.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/noty_theme_default.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/uploadify.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/chosen.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/jquery.gritter.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/font-awesome.min.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/fullcalendar.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/filetypes.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/glyphicons.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/social.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/xcharts.min.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css  app.herokuapp.com/:1160
GET http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/halflings.css
```

All of these CSS files are in the same directory (assets/simpliq) as the `import.less` file. And my assets are precompiled using:

`config.assets.precompile += %w( theme.js simpliq/* page_specific_manifests/* page_specific_files/* libraries/* )`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try the `css` or `inline` option when importing your CSS, see also: http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature. Note that i do not see what kind of error you got?

Comment: If I read correctly, first you include the bootstrap.min file and then the "custom" styles.. If the bootstrap file is processed (not `@import 'simpliq/bootstrap.min.css'`) then you should use the `less` option when importing the css files. You shouldn't put anything before the css `@import`s (except comments).

Comment: @BassJobsen and I tried that, it wouldn't precompile :/ There error I've been getting is all of the "GET"s that you see above.

Comment: @madcorp I tried directives, they won't precompile

Comment: @trevorhinesley can you open these files from your browser? Or did you check the permissions?

Comment: Beacuse I miss the "5min window" for editing: You "say" that all files are in `assets/simpliq`, but generated URLs are `http://app.herokuapp.com/assets/jquery.cleditor.css` - missing `simpliq`. I'll suggest to check your scripts/code/files. :)

Comment: @madcorp that's because I added `simpliq/*` to my precompiled assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only able to fix this by adding `.less` to each of the css files. For instance, `@import "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css";` became `@import "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css.less";`

Comment: As I mentioned before, to use `less` option, the `@import "any_file.css.less";` is the same as `@import (less) "any_file.css"` (or any other file, the extension doesn't matter). For reference - http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options

Comment: @madcorp as I mentioned before, that doesn't work. I tried it, and it won't precompile.